# Prevent prepopulation of msgstr values in new PO files generated via msginit program of gettext

Tags: localization, translation, gettext, po, pot

By default, when generating a PO file using the `msginit` command of the `gettext` package according to their [source](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/msginit-Invocation.html), the
`msgstr` values are prepopulated with the corresponding `msgid` values, so you get sth like this in your PO file..:

```
#. Message for unknown errors
#: /Http/Response.php:367
msgid "An unknown error occurred."
msgstr "An unknown error occurred."
```

created with a command like this:

```
msginit --input=mydomain_source.pot \
      --locale=fr_FR.UTF-8 \
      --no-wrap \
      --no-translator \
      --output-file="mydomain-fr_FR.po"
```

The .pot file of course does not contain any `msgstr` values, and has been generated using the [xgettext](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/xgettext-Invocation.html) command.

The desired output should instead not hold any `msgstr` values:

```
#. Message for unknown errors
#: /Http/Response.php:367
msgid "An unknown error occurred."
msgstr ""
```

Is there a way to prevent this in gettext, or is this a bug? Or actually intended behaviour?? We're only having this problem with the `msginit` command, when using the `msgmerge` command of the gettext package, no default msgstr values get pasted.

Answer (score 0):

`msginit` does not behave in the way you describe. If your `.po` file contains `msgstr` entries you have created it in another way. The documentation that you refer to also does not say that `msginit` pre-populates `msgstr` entries except for the meta information. The meta information - sometimes called the po-headers - is the `msgstr` for the `msgid` '""' (the empty string) but that is not your problem here.

Furthermore, the `msginit` and `msgmerge` commands have totally different purposes.  You use `msginit` to create a new and empty translation file for a new language that you support.  The `msgmerge` command is used to update an existing `.po` file with new translatable strings from a `.pot` file, a po template file.